# MSIX randomly not installing Windows service

Tags: windows, maui, msix

I have a Windows desktop application build using Maui and installed using an MSIX installer. A key part of the desktop application is a Windows service which should be installed by the MSIX installer.

I've found that randomly however it does not install the service. The installer also does not throw any error causing end users to open up the app only for it to crash (because of a missing service).

What I've found:

- On a system where the app has not been installed before the service gets installed without problems
- At any point when updating the app with a newer version or simply reinstalling the app the service might be missing afterwards
- Once you get in a state where the service is missing no amount of reboots or reinstalls can fix the problem with one exception: installing a completely new version can fix the problem (for example: upgrading from 1.6.0 to 1.7.0 can fix the problem, same for downgrading).
- Windows event viewer does not report any errors or problems as far as I've found (checked the `AppXDeployment-Server` logs)
- The installer does prompt for elevated rights

I'm sure I probably made a mistake in my `appxmanifest` but I don't see it. Any help would be appreciated.

Our `appxmanifest` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  xmlns:desktop="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10"
  xmlns:desktop6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10/6"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap rescap">

  <Identity Name="NAME" Publisher="PUBLISHER" Version="0.0.0.0" />

  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>NAME</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>NAME</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>$placeholder$.png</Logo>
  </Properties>

  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.17763.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.19041.0" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.17763.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.19041.0" />
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop" MinVersion="14.0.24217.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
  </Dependencies>

  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>

  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">
      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="$placeholder$"
        Description="$placeholder$"
        Square150x150Logo="$placeholder$.png"
        Square44x44Logo="$placeholder$.png"
        BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Square71x71Logo="$placeholder$.png" Wide310x150Logo="$placeholder$.png" Square310x310Logo="$placeholder$.png" />
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="$placeholder$.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
      <Extensions>
          <desktop:Extension Category="windows.startupTask" Executable="NAME.exe" EntryPoint="MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp">
            <desktop:StartupTask TaskId="NAME" Enabled="true" DisplayName="NAME" />
          </desktop:Extension>
          <desktop6:Extension
          Category="windows.service"      
          Executable="SERVICE_EXECUTABLE.exe"
          EntryPoint="SERVICE_NAMESPACE.Program">
            <desktop6:Service
              Name="SERVICE_NAME"
              StartupType="auto"
              StartAccount="localSystem"
              Arguments="/manage"
          >
          </desktop6:Service>
        </desktop6:Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>

  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="allowElevation" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="packagedServices" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="packageManagement" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="localSystemServices" />
  </Capabilities>

</Package>
```

Comment: It is the uninstall of the previous service that is stopping you, not the install of the current. I had those problems before. (Also this is usually not related to MAUI in any way.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. What kind of problems did you run into before that caused the uninstall to cause issues?

Comment: I do not know. It was long ago, I failed to make it uninstall already installed and running service. I switched to WiX. It worked. Accepted my miracle, and moved on. But I remember, that the big problem was, that some mess is becoming after the installer failed. I had to stop it, restart the machine, remove it by hand, and then run the new install. If I uninstalled the service before I run the installer, everything else worked fine. I know I am not helping you much. Just wanted to share.

Comment: Hi, any info helps. I'll try and see if I can use this to come up with a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to create a new project to test the MSIX package?

Comment: Not yet, I'd love to create a minimal example showcasing the issue (or the absence of the issue in that case) however the end customer needs to allocate time for this in our project. I will push for this though.

Comment: Just to be complete I did already report a bug in the issue tracker at Github https://github.com/microsoft/msix-packaging/issues/558